# How to stack numpy array along an axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, one with shape let's say (10, 5, 200), and another one with the shape (1, 200), how can I stack them so I get as a result an array of dimensions (10, 6, 200)? Basically by stacking it to each 2-d array iterating along the first dimension

```py
a = np.random.random((10, 5, 200))
b = np.zeros((1, 200))
```

I'v tried with hstack and vstack but I get an error in incorrect number of axis

Comment: `a` is 3d, `b` 2d.  If `b` as (10,1,200) you could easily concatenate on axis 1.  You could expand `b` to (1,1,200) and then repeat.  Or makes (10,6,200) array of zeros, and assign values (with broadcasting).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
a = np.random.random((10, 5, 200))
b = np.zeros((1, 200))
```

Let's look at the volume (number of elements) of each array:

The volume of `a` is `10*5*200` = 10000.
The volume of an array with (10,6,200) is `10*5*200=1200`.

That is you want to create an array that has 2000 more elements.
However, the volume of `b` is 1*200 = 200.

This means `a` and `b` can't be stacked.

Comment: Thanks, I just have solved it using np.pad, since the b array is always constant

Comment: Edited the post to show the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

As [hpaulj mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), one way is to define an numpy array and then fill it:

```
result = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[1] + b.shape[0], a.shape[2]))
result[:, :a.shape[1], :] = a
result[:, a.shape[1]:, :] = b
```